# How do i delete 2 textboxes when i click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a form whereby users can click on the add button to produce 2 more textboxes at every click. It works perfectly fine until i added in a function name deleterow(). Once i added that function, my addrow() does not work anymore.
This are my codes for addrow().

```
<button onclick ="addRow()" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
<button onclick ="deleterow()" value ="Reset">Reset</button>        
<script>
    var x=1
    var count=0;

    function addRow()
    {

        if(count <= 10)
        {
            var d = document.getElementById('div');
            d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='txta"+ x +"'><span class =wordtab></span>";
            d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='txtb"+ x +"'><br><br>";
            count++;
            x++
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Maximum 10 Skills");
        }
    }
```

These are my codes for deleterow(). I am also not sure if my codes are correct for deleting 2 'latest' textboxes everytime i click on the delete button.

```
    function deleterow()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
        var element1 = document.getElementById('txta'+i); // will return element
        element1.parentNode.removeChild(element1); // will remove the element from DOM  
        var element2 = document.getElementById('txtb'+i); // will return element
        element2.parentNode.removeChild(element2); // will remove the element from DOM
        }

    }
</script>
<div id="div">
```

Oh and lastly, how can i do so that everytime i add a new row, my buttons will automatically be below all of the text boxes. Currently, it will be stuck at the top of the page. Thanks!:)

This is my css

```
.wordtab 
        {
            min-width: 85px; 
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

This is my current output if i were to insert 11 rows and delete row number 5 and 6.

[image]

[image]

This is my output when i delete all 11 rows and add 2 more rows

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you can directly use `$(element).remove()`.  Also you function `deleterow` will delete all textboxes. Instead, pass row number and delete necessary items only.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console? (Press F12 to open it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using jquery you could use click events instead of inline `onclick`

I think you should add reset button to every line so you could remove it, for the the add button *it will be stuck at the top of the page.* you have just to place it after the div.

Check the example bellow, this helps.

---

```js
var x=1;
var count=0;

//click Event for the add button
$('body').on('click','#add',function(){
  if(count <= 10){
    //add the two inputs + the reset button to a div with class 'line' then append 
    //this div to #div

    $('#div').append("<div class='line'><input type='text' id='txta"+ x +"'><span class='wordtab'></span><input type='text' id='txtb"+ x +"'><button class='delete' value='Reset'>Reset</button></div>");
    count++;
    x++
  }
  else
    alert("Maximum 10 Skills");
});

//click Event for the delete button
$('body').on('click','.delete',function(){

  //when the user click on delete get the parent div with class 'line' of clickable 
  //button and remove it

  $(this).closest('.line').remove(); 
  count--;
});
```

```css
.wordtab 
{
  min-width: 85px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.line{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button id='add' value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: wow omg this is actually what i am looking for!:) thank you so so so much! but the codes look very complex. Dont understand half of the codes. hmmm but anyways thank you so much! if you dont mind can you explain the codes to me? that would be brilliant!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thanks! hmm i found a 'loophole' in this code. If i were to add in lets say 7 rows, and i would like to delete row number 5. It will leave a blank in between row 4 and 6. And if i delete row 1-6 and left 7 there. it will be in the middle of the page. How can i do about it?

Comment: That depending to your css code (the snippet leave no blank), you have to create a jsFiddle example or you could add the relevant css to your OP so i can verify it.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have added in my css file but honestly i did not do anything about css with this php yet.

Comment: I have also added it to css but there's no change check https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/o26j7ets/3/, add screenshot of your output if you can.

Comment: If the snippet in my answer and the fiddle works fine in your machine so that definitely a css code somewhere that do this..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki hmm i doubt so because i tried not including my css file but it still gives me the same problem

Comment: emm that strange which browser are you using? is the fiddle and snippet give the same problem ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Nope it does not give me the same problem. Im currently using google chrome for my project.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ohhh! i know what is the problem i added a break at the end of this $('#div').append("<div class='line'><input type='text' id='txta"+ x +"'><span class =wordtab></span><input type='text' id='txtb"+ x +"'><span class =wordtab></span><button class='delete' value ='Delete Row'>Delete Row</button></div><br>");

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki so whenever i delete the roll i only delete that line but not the break. it will keep on adding. hmm do you know how to add in to the function where it will delete both the break and the line? thanks !!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Hi do you still happen to know if i can delete break together with the textbox everytime i click on the button? much thanks

Comment: Hi @Samuel i suggest to use CSS instead of line break by adding `margin-bottom: 15px;` to the `div`s with class `.line` check my update. (glad i could helps)